# Multi-Classification NN with Keras error

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I am getting an error when trying to do multi-classification with three classes.

```
Error: TypeError: fit_generator() got multiple values for argument 'steps_per_epoch'
```

Code Giving Error:

```
NN.fit_generator(
                        train_set, train_labels,
                        steps_per_epoch=(train_samples/ batch_size),
                        epochs=epochs,
                        validation_data=(validation_set, validation_labels),
                        validation_steps=(validation_samples / batch_size))
```

Full Code: https://pastebin.com/V1YwJW3X

I would GREATLY appreciate any help with the issue, as I am at a total loss. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#fit_generator) provides the following definition for `fit_generator`:

```
fit_generator(self, generator, steps_per_epoch=None, epochs=1, verbose=1, callbacks=None, validation_data=None, validation_steps=None, class_weight=None, max_queue_size=10, workers=1, use_multiprocessing=False, shuffle=True, initial_epoch=0)
```

You have provided two positional arguments:

- `train_set` - this got assigned to `generator`
- `train_labels` - this got assigned to `steps_per_epoch`

But then you provide another (now keyword argument) `steps_per_epoch`, hence the error.