# Error - Multi-Classification Neural Network using Keras

Tags: python, compiler-errors, keras, conv-neural-network

I am receiving a rather annoying error from my NN code, and was hoping that someone with a better knowledge of how Keras works may explain to me why I am getting the error. I appreciate any help!
Error:

```
AttributeError: 'DirectoryIterator' object has no attribute 'ndim'
```

The error is coming from:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Cameron\Desktop\AI\CubeFieldNN_Train -fix.py", line 80, in <module>
    validation_steps = (validation_samples / batch_size))
```

Code:

```
NN.fit(
train_set, train_labels,
batch_size = batch_size,
epochs = epochs,
validation_data = (validation_set, validation_labels),
validation_steps = (validation_samples / batch_size))
```

Full Code: https://pastebin.com/V1YwJW3X

Full Error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Cameron\Desktop\AI\CubeFieldNN_Train -fix.py", line 80, in <module>
    validation_steps = (validation_samples / batch_size))
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py", line 1002, in fit
    validation_steps=validation_steps)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1630, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1476, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='input')
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 76, in _standardize_input_data
    data = [np.expand_dims(x, 1) if x is not None and x.ndim == 1 else x for x in data]
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 76, in <listcomp>
    data = [np.expand_dims(x, 1) if x is not None and x.ndim == 1 else x for x in data]
AttributeError: 'DirectoryIterator' object has no attribute 'ndim'
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The transition to `fit` from `fit_generator` from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50182263/multi-classification-nn-with-keras-error/50183265#50183265) was not really necessary. 
The [`flow_from_directory`](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#flow_from_directory) returns a generator type object which returns tuples of both the data and the labels. Similarly for `validation_set`. Note also, that if you specify `validation_steps` you have to also specify `steps_per_epoch`. Therefore, you can use:

```
NN.fit_generator(train_set,
                 steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
                 epochs=epochs,
                 validation_data=validation_set,
                 validation_steps=validation_steps)
```

Alternatively, you can load all images at once and pass it to the `NN.fit()` function along with the labels as you did.

Comment: I did not realize that they returned the labels as well, I thank you greatly for pointing that out. Thank you!

Comment: Okay, maybe I did know that it returned labels. Though, it does not return them correctly. After training, I get weird answers like "[[0.000000e+00 7.721626e-16 0.000000e+00]]" instead of [0,1,0]. Would you happen to know why this could be?

Comment: That is an expected output. Remember, your last layer is `sigmoid` layer. To get the class you can either call an `argmax` function on the output or use `model.predict_classes()` to receive these classes. So instead of [0.2, 0.7, 0.1] you will receive [1], instead [0.0, 0.3, 0.7] you will receive [2] etc.

Comment: Following the TF Documentation, one should use fit() (At present time). More info here: [TF Documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit)