# TypeError: fit_generator() got multiple values for argument 'steps_per_epoch'

Tags: machine-learning, python, keras

I am trying to train keras model. Below is the function for train model.

```
def train_model(input_videos, video_label, mapping, micro_expressions, val_x=None, val_micro=None, val_y=None, return_best=False):
    print("train_model")
    input_videos = np.asarray(input_videos)
    data_x, data_y, data_mapping, data_micro = H1_preprocessing(input_videos, video_label, mapping, micro_expressions)
    model, callbacks_lst = build_model()
    print("data_x: ", data_x.shape)
    print("data_y: ", data_y.shape)
    if val_x is not None and val_y is not None and val_micro is not None:
        hist = model.fit_generator([data_x, data_micro[0], data_micro[1], data_micro[2]], data_y, steps_per_epoch = 2, epochs = 20, verbose = 2, callbacks = callbacks_lst, validation_data=([val_x, val_micro[0], val_micro[1], val_micro[2]], val_y), use_multiprocessing=True, shuffle=True)
        print(hist) 
    else:
        hist = model.fit_generator([data_x, data_micro[0], data_micro[1], data_micro[2]], data_y, steps_per_epoch = 2, epochs = 20, verbose = 2, callbacks = callbacks_lst, use_multiprocessing=True, shuffle=True)
        print(hist)

    if return_best:
        print("Applying weights")
        model.load_weights("weights.best.hdf5")
        model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

The fit_generator() function creates error. I am not aware of providing right parameters at right position. It shows the following error.

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "concatenated_classifier.py",
> line 697, in trained_model = train_model(list_gray_train_videos,
> list_train_label, clips_mapping, micro_expressions, None, None, None,
> True) File "concatenated_classifier.py", line 613, in train_model hist
> = model.fit_generator([data_x, data_micro[0], data_micro1, data_micro[2]], data_y, steps_per_epoch = 2, epochs = 20, verbose = 2,
> callbacks = callbacks_lst, use_multiprocessing=True, shuffle=True)
> File
> "C:\Users\Me\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py",
> line 91, in wrapper return func(*args, **kwargs) TypeError:
> fit_generator() got multiple values for argument 'steps_per_epoch'

Suggest me where to provide steps_per_epoch and data_y.

Answer (score 0):

The error is that you are first providing two positional arguments `[data_x, data_micro[0], data_micro[1], data_micro[2]]` and `data_y` and given that the `steps_per_epoch` argument is the second argument of `fit_generator` (see [tensorflow docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit_generator)) the variable `data_y` will be used for the `steps_per_epoch` argument. You then provide another value for `steps_per_epoch` using a keyword argument, which is causing the error. See also [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50183265/9435355). To solve this make sure to only provide on positional argument, which should be a data generator.